# Copy vector of vectors into 1D array

Tags: c++

I have following C++ object

```
std::vector<std::vector<SomeClass>> someClassVectors(sizeOFOuter);
```

where I know the size of "outer" vector, but sizes of "inner" vectors varies. I need to copy the elements of this structure into 1D array like this:

```
SomeClass * someClassArray;
```

I have a solution where I use std::copy like this

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfOuter; i++)
{
   std::copy(someClassVectors[i].begin(), someClassVectors[i].end(), &someClassArray[count]);
   count += someClassVectors[i].size();
}
```

but the class includes large matrices which means I cannot have the "vectors" structure and 1D array allocated twice at the same time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Move the objects instead of copying them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004517/moving-elements-from-stdvector-to-another-one

Answer (score 3):

Do you previously preallocate `someClassArray` to a given size? I'd suggest using 1D vector for getting rid of known problems with the plain array if possible.

what about something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

     std::vector<std::vector<int>>  someClassVectors {
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,9}
     };

    std::vector<int> flat;  
    while (!someClassVectors.empty())
    {
       auto& last = someClassVectors.back();
    
       std::move(std::rbegin(last), std::rend(last), std::back_inserter(flat));
    
       someClassVectors.pop_back();
    }
    
    std::reverse(std::begin(flat), std::end(flat));
    
    int * someClassArray = flat.data();

    std::copy(someClassArray, someClassArray + flat.size(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

}
```

The extra reverse operation doesn't have an effect on memory metrics - such an approach helps to avoid unneeded memory reallocations resulting from removing vector elements from beginning to end.

**EDIT**
Inspired by comments I changed copy to move semantics

Comment: There's a [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) algorithm you can use instead of `std::copy` + `std::make_move_iterator`. You also don't want const iterators for the to-be-moved-from range.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I was about to ask about `std::make_move_iterator(std::crbegin(last))`  etc. That seems like it should be illegal, but `g++` is allowing it even with `-std=c++2a -Wall -Werror`. How is it legal to convert a `const` iterator to one that moves from the source?!?

Answer (score 2):

Embrace [Range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) (or whatever will be introduced in C++20) and write a solution in (almost) a single line:

```cpp
auto flattenedRange = ranges::views::join(someClassVectors);
```

this gives you a range in `flattenedRange`, which you can loop over or copy somewhere else easily.

This is a possible use case:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> Ints2D = {
        {1,2,3},
        {4},
        {5,6}
    };

    auto Ints1D = ranges::views::join(Ints2D);
    // here, going from Ints1D to a C-style array is easy, and shown in the other answer already

    for (auto const& Int : Ints1D) {
        std::cout << Int << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    // output is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 
}
```

In case you want to get a true `std::vector` instead of a range, before writing it into a C-style array, you can include this other header

```cpp
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
```

and pipe `join`'s output into a conversion function:

```cpp
    auto Ints1D = ranges::views::join(Ints2D) | ranges::to_vector;
    // auto deduces std::vector<int>
```

In terms of standard and versions, it doesn't really require much. In [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7Ted3G) you can see that it compiles and runs just fine with

- compiler GCC 7.3
- library Range-v3 0.9.1
- C++14 standard (option `-std=c++14` to `g++`)

### As regards the copies

- `ranges::views::join(Ints2D)` is only creating a *view* on `Ints2D`, so no copy happens; if *view* doesn't make sense to you, you might want to give a look at [Chapter 7](https://livebook.manning.com/book/functional-programming-in-c-plus-plus/chapter-7/) from [Functional Programming in C++](https://livebook.manning.com/book/functional-programming-in-c-plus-plus/about-this-book/), which has a very clear explanation of ranges, with pictures and everything;¹
- even assigning that output to a variable, `auto Ints1D = ranges::views::join(Ints2D);`, does *not* trigger a copy; `Ints1D` in this case is *not* a `std::vector<int>`, even though it behaves as one when we loop on it (behaves as a vector because it's a view on it);
- converting it to a vector, e.g. via  `| ranges::to_vector`, obviously triggers a copy, because you are no more requesting a view on a vector, but a true one;
- passing the range to an algorithm which loops on its elements doesn't trigger a copy.

Here's an example code that you can try out:

```cpp
// STL
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
// Boost and Range-v3
#include <boost/range/algorithm/for_each.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>

struct A {
    A() = default;
    A(A const&) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; };
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<A>> Ints2D = {
        {A{},A{}},
        {A{},A{}}
    };
    using boost::range::for_each;
    using ranges::to_vector;
    using ranges::views::join;
    std::cout << "no copy, because you're happy with the range\n";
    auto Ints1Dview = join(Ints2D);
    std::cout << "copy, because you want a true vector\n";
    auto Ints1D = join(Ints2D) | to_vector;
    std::cout << "copy, despite the refernce, because you need a true vector\n";
    auto const& Ints1Dref = join(Ints2D) | to_vector;
    std::cout << "no copy, because we movedd\n";
    auto const& Ints1Dref_ = join(std::move(Ints2D)) | to_vector;
    std::cout << "no copy\n";
    for_each(join(Ints2D), [](auto const&){ std::cout << "hello\n"; });
}
```

¹ In an attempt to try giving a clue of what a range is, I would say that you can imagine it as a thing wrapping two iterators, one poiting to the `end` of the range, the other one pointing to the `begin` of the range, the latter being incrementable via `operator++`; this opearator will take care of the jumps in the correct way, for instance, after viewing the element `3` in `Ints2D` (which is in `Ints2D[0][2]`), `operator++` will make the iterator jump to view the elment `Ints[1][0]`.

Comment: but does this `ranges::views::join(...)` get rid of `Ints2D` or does it actually "copy" it into other object?

Comment: @mathys, the short answer to your question is _no, it doesn't copy_. In my answer I've explained a bit better what happens.