# How to move STL vector to protobuf RepeatedPtrValue?

Tags: c++, stl, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to move STL vector to protobuf repeated?
The following code works but I think it is copyng the values, not moving the values.

```
// foo.proto
message Foo {
  int64 a = 1;
  int64 b = 2;
}
message FooList {
  repeated Foo foos = 1;
}

// main.cc
FooList foo_list;
vector<Foo> v;
v.push_back({1,2});
v.push_back({3,4});
foo_list.mutable_foos() = {v.begin(), v.end()};
```

Comment: Use a `std::move_iterator`?

Comment: maybe dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004517/moving-elements-from-stdvector-to-another-one

Comment: Thanks for comment. Does this work for the protocol buffer?

Comment: Not sure.  I think it should but you can test by using a class that shows if it is getting moved

Comment: Ah thanks! I will try 
`foo_list.mutable_foos() = {make_move_iterator(v.begin()), make_move_iterator(v.end()) };`